# how to send data as hidden to QComboBOX in pyqt

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, qcombobox

I need to send `name` and `id` to `QComboBox`, But i want to `show` `name` and because `id` is id in dB table, i want to keep as hidden `id`, but i don’t know how to keep as hidden `id`.
I can name such as:

```
self.comboBox_2.addItems(list1)
```

Bu i don't have any idea on hidden data.

**My question** is , how send data as hidden to `QComboBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a data model based on `QAbstractItemModel` which has to columns 'id' and 'name', you can do this:

```
enum Columns
{
    COL_ID,
    COL_NAME
}

QComboBox *combo = new QComboBox;
combo->setModel(model);
combo->setModelColumn(COL_NAME)
```

If you want to add items to a combobox one by one, you do this:

```
QComboBox *combo = new QComboBox;
combo->addItem(name, id);
```

Then you can retrieve id value from combobox item using:

```
QString id = combo->itemData(index, Qt::UserRole).toString();
```